# Detox does not run tests on Android but works fine on iOS

Tags: android, json, react-native, detox

The application's tests run fine on iOS but it just is stuck on the splash screen.

I have run the build command for android which created the build perfectly fine. When upon running test command to run the E2E test the app gets installed but it does not execute any test.

The application gets installed for the tests but no tests are run. It seems as detox server is not able to find and UI elements with test ID.

below is some part from the package.json file.

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-beta.47",
    "babel-jest": "^23.2.0",
    "detox": "10.0.3",
    "eslint-config-rallycoding": "^3.2.0",
    "jest": "^23.4.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.4.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
"devDependencies": {
        "babel-core": "^7.0.0-beta.47",
        "babel-jest": "^23.2.0",
        "detox": "10.0.3",
        "eslint-config-rallycoding": "^3.2.0",
        "jest": "^23.4.2",
        "react-test-renderer": "16.4.1"
      },
      "detox": {
        "test-runner": "jest",
        "specs": "e2e",
        "configurations": {
          "ios.sim.debug": {
            "binaryPath": "ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/hektor.app",
            "build": "cd ios && xcrun xcodebuild -workspace hektor.xcworkspace -scheme hektor -configuration Debug -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone X,OS=12.1'  -derivedDataPath build && cd ..",
            "type": "ios.simulator",
            "name": "iPhone X"
          },

          "android.emu.debug": {
            "binaryPath": "android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk",
            "build": "cd android && ./gradlew assembleDebug assembleAndroidTest -DtestBuildType=debug && cd ..",
            "type": "android.attached",
            "name": "2e1c66bf",
            "adb": "2e1c66bf"
          }
        }
      }
}
```

Am sharing the link of the repo on which I uploaded the end to end tests code.

https://github.com/waneed-plero/e2e-tests.git

Dependencies:

React Native: 0.56.0

Node: 11.9.0

Device: android

Comment: Where you able to fix this?

Comment: With android, no we were not. So, we decided to go with Jest.